# react axios post constantly

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

I used Axios with useEffect,
Axios post constantly.

**These are my codes.**

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.post("/estimate", { nana: "nana" }).then(res => alert(res.data));
}, []);
```

[this is a record of the flask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VTsL.png)

Comment: Don't see any problem with your code, Could you please provide more context?

Comment: can you provide you frontend code. its probably cause of some infinite loop.

Comment: I added frontend code in Anser!

Comment: you are supposed to edit your question instead of adding it as the answer. There is a chance your question will be flagged otherwise. if you make the appropriate change it will be helpful for the community.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Banner from "./Home/Banner";
import Content from "./Home/Content";
import Feature from "./Home/Feature";
import Advantages from "./Home/Advantages";
import End from "./Home/End";
import axios from "axios";

function Home() {
  const [starEndHeight, setStarEndHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post("/estimate");
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Banner />
      <Content starEndHeight={starEndHeight} />
      <Feature />
      <Advantages />
      <End setStarEndHeight={setStarEndHeight} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: <End setStarEndHeight={setStarEndHeight} />, remove this. this is making the page refresh everytime. since it is for setting state. so everytime state changes component reloads.

Answer (score 0):

```
<End setStarEndHeight={setStarEndHeight} />
```

Remove that attribute or give a different name other than what you have used for the state hook. that line is making the page refresh everytime. since it is for setting state. so everytime state changes component reloads.